# Completely removing duplicate items from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's assume that I have ;

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,4,5,5];
```

I want it to be;

```
var newArray = [1,2,3];
```

I want to remove the duplicates completely rather than keeping them as unique values. Is there a way achieve that through reduce method ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array)

Comment: why not use filter?

Comment: To clarify, if a number appears more than once, you want to remove ALL instances of that number - is that correct? So your desired output would be `[1,2,3]`?

Comment: I don't want to get the duplicate values. I want to remove them completely.

Comment: @mhodges that's correct.

Comment: do you need the same array?

Comment: @zer00ne I don't think you understand the question

Comment: @mhodges rid of them completely I see

Comment: So you'll need to store values and if they're repeated, remove all of them. If the repeated elements are sequential, it's fairly straight forward, but a little more difficult if they aren't.

Comment: @mhodges Mate, with removing *Is there a way achieve that through reduce method?* you have totally changed the question purpose.

Comment: @Kinduser Most OPs don't know what they don't know. You have to give them the benefit of the doubt. [I'll just leave this here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [`Array#lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) and return only the values which share the same index.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5],
    result = array.filter(function (v, _, a) {
        return a.indexOf(v) === a.lastIndexOf(v);
    });

console.log(result);
```

Another approach by taking a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and set the value to `false`, if a key has been seen before. Then filter the array by taking the value of the map.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5],
    result = array.filter(
        Map.prototype.get,
        array.reduce((m, v) => m.set(v, !m.has(v)), new Map)
    );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Didn't think of `lastIndexOf` - great solution!

Comment: This is beautiful. I hadn't thought of lastIndexOf either.

Comment: Nice! The second example is better in terms of algorithm order; and it has a very clever use of thisArg in filter that I just learn by reading the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I guess it won't have some remarkable performance, but I like the idea.

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,4,5,5],
    res = array.reduce(function(s,a) {
      if (array.filter(v => v !== a).length == array.length-1) {
        s.push(a);
      }
      return s;
    }, []);
    console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use an object to track how many times an element is used.  This will destroy the array order, but it should be much faster on very large arrays.

```js
function nukeDuplications(arr) {
  const hash = {};
  arr.forEach(el => {
    const qty = hash[el] || 0;
    hash[el] = qty+1;
  });
  
  const ret = [];
  Object.keys(hash).forEach(key => {
    if (hash[key] === 1) {
      ret.push(Number(key));
    }
  })
  return ret;
}

var array = [1,2,3,4,4,5,5];
console.log(nukeDuplications(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more efficient solution would be to loop over the array 1 time and count the number of occurrences in each value and store them in an object using `.reduce()` and then loop over the array again with `.filter()` to only return items that occurred 1 time.

This method will also preserve the order of the array, as it merely uses the object keys as references - it does not iterate over them.

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,4,5,5];
var valueCounts = array.reduce((result, item) => {
    if (!result[item]) {
        result[item] = 0;
    }
    result[item]++;
    return result;
}, {});
 
var unique = array.filter(function (elem) {
    return !valueCounts[elem] || valueCounts[elem] <= 1;
}); 
 
console.log(unique)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use an object to track how many times an element is used.  This will destroy the array order, but it should be much faster on very large arrays.

```js
// Both versions destroy array order.

// ES6 version
function nukeDuplications(arr) {
  "use strict";
  const hash = {};
  arr.forEach(el => {
    const qty = hash[el] || 0;
    hash[el] = qty + 1;
  });

  const ret = [];
  Object.keys(hash).forEach(key => {
    if (hash[key] === 1) {
      ret.push(Number(key));
    }
  })
  return ret;
}

// ES5 version
function nukeDuplicationsEs5(arr) {
  "use strict";
  var hash = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var el = arr[i];
    var qty = hash[el] || 0;
    hash[el] = qty + 1;
  };

  var ret = [];
  for (let key in hash) {
    if (hash.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (hash[key] === 1) {
          ret.push(Number(key));
        }
      }
    }
    return ret;
  }


  var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5];
  console.log(nukeDuplications(array));

  console.log(nukeDuplicationsEs5(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of over-complicated, and slow running code here. Here's my solution:

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5]
let filtered = []

numbers.map((n) => {
    if(numbers.indexOf(n) === numbers.lastIndexOf(n)) // If only 1 instance of n
        filtered.push(n)
})

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function:

```js
function isUniqueInArray(array, value) {
  let counter = 0;
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    if (array[index] === value) {
      counter++;
    }
  }
  if (counter === 0) {
    return null;
  }
  return counter === 1 ? true : false;
}

const array = [1,2,3,4,4,5,5];
let uniqueValues = [];

array.forEach(element => {
  if(isUniqueInArray(array ,element)){
    uniqueValues.push(element);
  }
});

console.log(`the unique values is ${uniqueValues}`);
```

If its help you, you can install the isUniqueInArray function from my package https://www.npmjs.com/package/jotils or directly from bit https://bit.dev/joshk/jotils/is-unique-in-array.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is used map and filter as below:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,2,3]
x.map(d => x.filter(i => i == d).length < 2 ? d : null).filter(d => d != null)
// [1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.values is supported since ES2017 (Needless to say - not on IE). 
The accumulator is an object for which each key is a value, so duplicates are removed as they override the same key. 
However, this solution can be risky with misbehaving values (null, undefined etc.), but maybe useful for real life scenarios.

```
let NukeDeps = (arr) => {
  return Object.values(arr.reduce((curr, i) => {
    curr[i] = i;
    return curr;
  }, {}))  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer my questions with an answer I came up with upon reading it again

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5];
const filtered = array.filter(item => {
  const { length }  = array.filter(currentItem => currentItem === item)
  if (length === 1) {
     return true;
   }
});
console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: One liner: `array.filter(x => array.filter(y => x === y).length === 1)`

Answer (score -1):

```
//Try with this code
var arr = [1,2, 3,3,4,5,5,5,6,6];

arr = arr.filter( function( item, index, inputArray ) {
           return inputArray.indexOf(item) == index;
      });
```

Also look into this link https://fiddle.jshell.net/5hshjxvr/