# im new to programming . I want to remove both duplicates from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

//My array

> const array[1,2,3,4,4,5,5]

//expected answer

> const newArray[1,2,3]

> Reminder i dont want to keep number 4 or 5 in the array i want to remove both

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates  this may help

Comment: `const newArray = array.filter((value, index, arr) => arr.indexOf(value) === index);` this should work. OR `const newArray = [...new Set(array)];`

Comment: Regarding your edit, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43505967/completely-removing-duplicate-items-from-an-array) is an _exact_ duplicate of yours.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that only the last linked question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43505967/completely-removing-duplicate-items-from-an-array) is a duplicate of yours, but that is an exact duplicate, even the sample array is the same.