# How to return array element with no duplicate ?? Javascript solution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mern

We have a array of numbers. let's say

```
const num = [ 10, 12, 4, 3, 5, 5, 10, 12 ];
```

Element with no duplicate is 4 and 3 in the 'num' array.
So function should return array such elements.
It would be better if some in-built methods (eg: filter, indexOf etc..) can be used in the solution.

```
input = [ 10, 12, 4, 3, 5, 5, 10, 12 ];
required output = [4, 3];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/14438954/11095009

Comment: @NeERAJTK No, that would return values that have duplicates. E.g., `10` and 12`. OP only wants the ones which have no duplicates.

Comment: I believe OP wants to remove completely any non-unique members of the array (count > 1).

Comment: Good duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43505967/completely-removing-duplicate-items-from-an-array

Comment: const num = [ 10, 12, 4, 3, 5, 5, 10, 12 ];

function uniqueVal(arr){
 let newArr  = arr.filter((e,i,a) => a.indexOf(e) !== i);
  return newArr;
}

Comment: getting opposite of what is required..@David